# How to genrate dynamically feild while selecting specific option from Select Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using Antd + Reactjs,( antd form, input and select option) to generat dynamically group of same feilds by clicking the button (+ send to).This is working properly but, I want to generate more feild according to the option by selecting from select Box in particularly row without changing the other feilds of all rows.
I have attached the images, so you can easyily answer this query.
[genrate feilds with send to button dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4IID.png)

[when select option from select box then new feild add called (sizer name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nmyu.png)

[when I select the comapny option from select box then sizer name is also remove from first row which is the main issue.I want to change feild on particular Row on which I select the option , remain row keep same according to the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuwRM.png)

**this is the code of feild which is genrated with send to button dynamically**

```
<Form.List name="variant_rate">
          {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {fields.map((field, index) => (
                  <Space
                    key={field.key}
                    style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                    align="start"
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "send_to"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "send_to"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Select where to send yarn",
                        },
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Select
                        onChange={sendToChnage}
                        onSelect={() => onSelect(index)}
                        placeholder="Send to"
                        Options={SendToOption}
                      />

                      {/* <Select
                        placeholder="Catagory"
                        Options={["A Catagory", "B Catagory", "C Catagory"]}
                      /> */}
                    </Form.Item>

                    {flag  ? (
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, "sizer_id"]}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "sizer_id"]}
                        rules={[
                          {
                            required: true,
                            message: "Please select Sizer Name",
                          },
                        ]}
                      >
                        <Select
                          placeholder="Sizer name"
                          type="sizerList"
                          Options={sizerList ? sizerList : [<LazyLoad />]}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    ) : null}
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "yarn_for"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "yarn_for"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Select for which yarn received",
                        },
                      ]}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    >
                      {/* <Input
                        placeholder="Quanitity"
                      
                      /> */}
                      <Select
                        placeholder="Yarn Recieved For"
                        Options={["warp", "weft"]}
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "slip_no_fac"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "slip_no_fac"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Factory Slip No is Required",
                        },
                      ]}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    >
                      <Input
                        placeholder="Factoy Slip No"
                        // prefix={<UserOutlined />}
                      />
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "fac_bag"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "fac_bag"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Please Enter Bags Quantity!",
                        },
                      ]}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    >
                      <StyledInputNumber placeholder="bags" />
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "fac_cons"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "fac_cons"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Please Enter Cons Quantity!",
                        },
                      ]}
                      style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    >
                      <StyledInputNumber placeholder="Cons" />
                    </Form.Item>

                    {/* {fields.length > 1 ? ( */}
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                    {/* ) : null} */}
                  </Space>
                ))}
                <Form.Item>
                  <Button
                    width="187px"
                    margin="auto"
                    fontSize="16px"
                    weight="500"
                    height="auto"
                    bg="#ba3d79"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                      // setVariant(true);
                    }}
                  >
                    <PlusOutlined /> Send To
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
```

**this is the onChange handler which is triger when you select the option from select box**

```
 const sendToChnage = (value, index) => {
console.log("value,index", value, index);
if (value === "sizer") setFlag(true);
else setFlag(false);
```

};

**this is the state which I used to hide or show the new feild (sizer name )**

```
const [flag, setFlag] = React.useState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while developing the a project i got it done by javascript events here is my some work that will help you

```
$(document).on("change", "select.last", function () {
        $("tr.productRow").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("last");
            $(this).addClass("first");
        });
        $("select.product").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("last");
            $(this).addClass("first");
        });
        $("input.last").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("required", "required");
            $(this).removeClass("last");
            $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
            $(this).addClass("first");
            $(this).val(1);
        });

        var selectedProduct = $(this).children("option:selected");
        var selectedProductPrice = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-price");
        var Quantity = $(this).parent("td").siblings("td").children("input.quantity").val();

        $(this).parent("td").next("td").children("input.price").val(selectedProductPrice);
        $(this)
            .parent("td")
            .siblings("td")
            .children("input.totalPrice")
            .val(selectedProductPrice * Quantity);

        $("#t_body").append(
            '<tr class="last productRow"> <td> <select name="products[]" class="form-control product last select2" data-live-search="true"  id="products"> <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Product</option> @foreach ($products as $key => $product) <option value="{{$product->id}}" data-price="{{ $product->price }}">{{ $product->name }}</option> @endforeach </select> </td> <td class="tdprice"> <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price[]" min="0" readonly > </td> <td class="tdquantity"> <input type="number" class="form-control quantity last" name="quantity[]" min="0" readonly> </td> <td class="tdtotalPrice"> <input type="number" class="form-control totalPrice" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice[]" min="0" readonly > </td> </tr>'
        );
        $(".select2").select2();
       
    });
```

Here i do select a product to generate invoice for customer and included fields dynamically to select another product.
First when you select any product it will replace the values according to product's price and quantity and you can change the quantity as much as you want and in the next when i select second product same code will run but it will not change anything in the first select product

```
 $(document.body).on("change", "select.first", function () {
        $(this).parent("td").siblings("td").children("input.quantity").val(1);
        var selectedProduct = $(this).children("option:selected");
        var selectedProductPrice = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-price");
        var Quantity = $(this).parent("td").siblings("td").children("input.quantity").val();

        $(this).parent("td").next("td").children("input.price").val(selectedProductPrice);

        $(this)
            .parent("td")
            .siblings("td")
            .children("input.totalPrice")
            .val(selectedProductPrice * Quantity);
        
    });
```

And this code will use when we change the first selected product to any other product again when we change the product it will replace the values according to product's values but i does not effect any other selected product as you can view the code.